# Creating a custom, dynamic Flash button that will work in Facebook shares

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, dynamic, button

I've had an issue with using [Facebook's Share feature](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share).

The user experience on the shared content below is just completely unclear (even when I tested some clarified language: e.g. "click here"). Users simply don't know what to do: they often either click "Like," or they comment with something along the lines of "I support you."

[image]

According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share), it is possible to share Flash content in these posts. I'm hoping I can create a "Support" button as an SWF button.

**Is it possible to dynamically create such an SWF with a custom *`href`? Will my use case work on Facebook? If you have an example, I'd love to see it.**

*I'm not sure `href` is even the proper term, as I don't use Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Facebook prevent SWFs to be used as buttons.

FB adds a "safe" image with a blue play button on top of your thumbnail image.  When this thumbnail is clicked, the FB page loads your SWF content.

[image]